# Get largest key from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I get the largest key in a dictionary which may have mixed data types? For example:

`myDict = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: None, 4: 1000}`

I want to get the largest key which is 4.  I tried `max(myDict)` which does work, but is this always reliable?  Or should I use `max(myDict.keys())` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The options you gave (`max(myDict)` and `max(myDict.keys())`) are equivalent, because `max` internally tries to iterate over the thing you pass to it. Iteration over a Python dictionary yields its keys, so, no real difference.